# There is no .xib file when I create a new "Single View Application" in XCode 5

Tags: xcode5

when i create a new project selecting option (single view application) in xcode 5, it automatically add Main.storyboard there is no option for selecting .Xib file as we select in previous version of xcode.
Please someone explain this

Comment: So is it an "Empty Application" or a "Single View Application"?

Comment: Single view application

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My suggestion is:

1. Create an empty app
2. Go to `File/New/File`, Choose Objective-C Class
3. Name your class `ViewController`(or whatever you like), make it subclass of  `UIViewController`
   Make sure you have checked the box "with xib for user interface."
4. Open `appDelegate.h`, put

> @class ViewController;

between `@interface and #import`, and this property below:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
```

1. Open your `appDelegate.m:` import your ViewController

> #import "ViewController.h"

and before

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

put

```
 self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

Comment: thats very clear thanks but only i think its better if you write "@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;"  after @interface.

Answer (score 10):

For adding XIB in xcode 5, use Empty application rather than single view application. Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632797/create-xib-based-interface-with-xcode-5/19633059#19633059%20%22question) for a simple way to integrate a XIB.