# Create xib based interface with Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xib

I am trying to create a new app with Singe View template but there is no xib or storyboard option to make my interface as xib file !!! why does Apple remove xib from iOS 7 ?!! How can I create application with xib interface files ?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- Create a new project
- Select Single View Application
- Set ProjectName and other settings
- Save Project at location
- Select Project in Navigator Panel in Left
- Remove Main.storyboard file from project
- Add New .xib file in Project
- Set Main Interface to your .xib file in "General Tab" on right panel.
- Paste following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

> ```
> self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
> self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
> [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Apple removed it because they just want to "force" everybody to use Storyboards, although from what I know, a big amount of people just don't find them useful.

I'm afraid you'll have to do it yourself, just create an empty app and set yourself the view.

Check an example:

http://www.appcoda.com/hello-world-app-using-xcode-5-xib/

Comment: Yeah, I know :) I use storyboards only in some specific situations

Comment: Sometimes I think they inspect storyboards during appstore review to see whether there are some secret screens hidden from them :)

Answer (score 5):

Apple remove it from xcode 5 . you have only one option to choose storyboard.
if you want to xibs then remove storyboard after creating singleView application and add xib manually.
another option is to create application in xcode 4.6 or earliar version then run it on xcode 5.