# How can i use xib files instead of storyboard in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xib

I'm very new to ios developing and many of the tutorials i watch follow the xib approach since they were recorded before XCode 5. How can i go with the xib approach in Single View Application? When i delete storyboard and select one of the xib's as the main interface it's not working. Thanks for any tip.

Comment: Hi..Its good to start programming on iOS Platform. All the Best for future challenges. You can find the tutorial in this link:http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: @HappyCoding, there are no materials on ray's site about using xib in xcode 5. If there is any can you post the link.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632797/create-xib-based-interface-with-xcode-5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add new file in that select the cococatouch and select the Objective -C class and then go to the next click.
you show the below screen 
at the bottom must select the with xib for user Interface.and next

AppDelegate.h:

```
@class ViewController;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    ViewController *viewObj;
    UINavigationController *navObj;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  ViewController *viewObj;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navObj;
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
@synthesize viewObj,window,navObj;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    viewObj = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    navObj = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewObj];

    window.rootViewController=navObj;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

[image]

Comment: In Xcode 9, how can we set it in "Main Interface" project option, without writing code.

Answer (score 7):

Select **Empty application template** while creating new project.

Select Cocoa touch from left pane -> objective-c class -> then give name of viewController and tick option of Xib user interface.

and then in **apply below code in appDelegate file:**

**appDelegate.h File:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface HomeAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong,nonatomic)HomeViewController *homeViewController;
@property (strong,nonatomic)UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

**appDelegate.m File:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.homeViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

  @end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by following these steps:-

- Create a new project
- Select Single View Application
- Set ProjectName and other settings
- Save Project at location
- Select Project in Navigator Panel in Left
- Remove Main.storyboard file from project
- Add New .xib file in Project
- Set Main Interface to your .xib file in "General Tab" on right panel.
- Paste following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

  ```
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  ```

Courtesy:- MKR

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19633059/1865424

Just check it have you missed any of the step.