# using .nib file instead of story board xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode6, nib

Problem outline :
.nib view displayed in simulator disappears instantly and a black screen is shown

Details:
I just started working with ios so please excuse me if this question sounds totally absurd. I am using xcode 6.2 I created a new Single View Application project. In xcode 6.2 a project has both a .nib file and a story board file.
Since I wanted to take the .nib file approach I changed the following

In Deployment info tab I changed MainInterface to `LaunchScreen` the name LaunchScreen is the name of my default generated .nib file. I then did the same for App Icons and launch Images section for `Launch Screen File`. Then I added a label to my .nib file and wrote something in that label. When I run the simulator my nib file gets displayed but then goes away. Unlike the tutorials that I follow which I believe are using older versions of xcode. Why is my .nib file simply fading away and a black screen being displayed in the simulator.Any suggestions on resolving this issue would be welcome.

Update:
In the deployment info in settings. If I change Main Interface to Main.storyboard the storyboard view appears on the simulator and stays there. However if I select the nib file instead of the storyboard the nib file gets displayed and then is instantly followed by a black screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the traditional way of coding and start with your Appdelegate.

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

```
UIViewController *landingViewControllerObj = [[LandingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LandingViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:landingViewControllerObj];
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

And create LandingViewController  with having nib file as well.

Answer (score 0):

The .nib is just for the launch image, not for the real UI. Info about that is [here, in the HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html).

Comment: is there a way for me to use the .nib file instead ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a [duplicate] question. Please refer to this original question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241120/how-can-i-use-xib-files-instead-of-storyboard-in-xcode-5)