# How do I add storyboard-based Header and CustomTableCell to a “Search Bar and Search Display Controller”

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uisearchbar

**PRESENTATION**

Mine is a simple project: It consists of a NavigationController, ViewController, and a “Search Bar and Search Display Controller”

My `.h` file is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

and my `.m` file is

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *data;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
    self.data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    // Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d", indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d: %@", indexPath.row, [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - delegate

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(mockSearch:) userInfo:searchString repeats:NO];
    return NO;
}

- (void)mockSearch:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    [_data removeAllObjects];
    int count = 1 + random() % 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        [_data addObject:timer.userInfo];
    }
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

And that’s the entire program. What does it do? User makes a search and the data is displayed in a TableView (similar to a google search).

**PROBLEM**

- I need to use a CustomTableViewCell for my table. And I need to build the TableViewCell from the storyboard (easy to visualize). I am stuck with the storyboard part. How do I place a TableViewCell on the storyboard without a TableView to place it in? I had an idea, I tried it, but it didn’t work. Here is what I did. I placed a “never-to-be-used” TableViewController in the storyboard whose sole purpose is to hold my CustomTableViewCell. Then in code I subclass TableViewCell and use IBOutlet to link the sub-views of the storyboard TableViewCell to my CustomTableViewCell . And then I used my cell as `CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`. This didn’t work. The tableView remained blank. And my guess for the failure is that `CustomTableViewCell` does not belong to the `tableView` being dequeued from.
- I need the UISearchBar to always stay inside the NavigationBar. But so far `self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;` is not doing it. When I first start the app the searchBar is inside the NavigationBar. But as soon as I click on it, it smacks itself right in the middle of my scene/screen and never leaves.
- I need to add a Header to my TableView. Which I thought of doing the same way as the CustomTableViewCell, but with a UIView parent class. But again, the CustomTableViewCell portion failed.

**PLEA**

Thank you for any help you can provide me.

**UPDATE**

All I am trying to do is allow my users to launch a server side search and view the results in a tableView. This is such a basic thing, I image many people here have done this a number of times. Being new to iOS, I am stuck. But at this point, I have posted my entire project (anyone can reconstruct it), and I have explained in details all the ways I tried to solve the problem. So if someone has a sample project they don’t mind sharing, it would help very much. Or if you know of a git project please put a link to it. Thanks.

Comment: Which table view do you want to use this custom cell for? The main one, or the search results table? Or do you even have a main table view, your question isn't clear about that.

Comment: BTW, you're not "stuck" with the storyboard part. If you want to make a stand alone cell, make it in a xib file, not a storyboard. You then use registerNib:forIdentifier: to tell your table view where to get its cell.

Comment: @rdelmar thanks! I didn't know I could visually create a standalone View except through storyboard. I am using iOS-7 and Xcode-5. I will look into this. Per your question: the answer is no, there is no main tableView. The only tableView I have comes from the item “Search Bar and Search Display Controller”; a necessary choice for loading from a server (http://patrickcrosby.com/2010/04/27/iphone-ipad-uisearchbar-uisearchdisplaycontroller-asynchronous-example.html).

Comment: @rdelmar according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632797/create-xib-based-interface-with-xcode-5 I would have to delete the storyboard to use xib. I am very new to iOS (I just finished taking a course titled "Developing iOS-7 apps for iPhone and iPad). I learn iOS development with the storyboard. I wouldn't know what to do without it. Do you know of a storyboard solution to the problem?

Comment: No, you do not have to delete a storyboard to add a xib file, that's just incorrect. Just go to "New File" --> User Interface --> Empty, and drag in a UITAbleViewCell.

Comment: @rdelmar Many thanks for the tip!! I create the cell in xib and pass the properties to a subclass. In `viewDidLoad` I called `[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:tableCell bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:tableCell]` But when I tap on searchBar it crash with 
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </…/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/9F55A0B8-96F7-49D2-A7C0-71567AD17D41/ServerSearchTwo.app> (loaded)' with name 'custom_cell’’`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57580/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-katedral-pillon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a stand-alone view (not in a view controller) in IB, then you should do it in a xib file, not a storyboard. You can have as many storyboard and xib files in an app as you want; they can be mixed freely. To make a new cell in a xib file, just go to New File --> User Interface --> Empty then drag in a UITableViewCell. Add any subviews you want, and in your table view controller (or whatever class is your table view data source), register the xib file with, registerNib:forIdentifier: (usually, you do this in viewDidLoad).